# When submitting analyses to FDA how does using R affect issues of software validation?

Tags: r, regression, bootstrap, errors-in-variables

I have worked on clinical trials in FDA submissions for many years. I use SAS almost exclusively. Recently I discussed a consulting job I had to bootstrap a Deming regression. Bootstrapping is much more easily done in R I think and several experts have suggested ways that I can do this in R. Since this is going into a resubmission to the FDA for my client I am concerned as to whether software validation might become an issue. I hear that R is gaining acceptance with the FDA and experts tell me that traceability which is an attractive feature with SAS can be dealt with easily in R as well.

My client did the original Deming regression with a package that I am not familiar with and validation was not an issue with the original submission. I want to help without adding any new headaches for them.

Can the R experts here give me some guidance? If it will help I can mention some of the programming options that were suggested?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but re bootstrapping in SAS, do you know of David Cassell's paper "Don't be Loopy"?

Comment: This is a bit open ended, and I'm not sure what you expect to hear that hasn't already been said in other questions, [R vs SAS, why is SAS prefered by private companies?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/33780/1036) and [Is the R language reliable for the field of economics?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/25811/1036). In particular, the comments [on your answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/33786/1036) to the SAS v R question seem sufficient to answer this (especially the Revo R [blog post](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/06/fda-r-ok.html) cited).

Comment: http://www.r-project.org/doc/R-FDA.pdf might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments thus far.  I will check out all the links! @PeterFlom I don't know that paper.  Does it have something to do with whether or not to imbed one procedure in another?  Anyway I would be curious to see it.  Can you provide a link?  Personally I think the bootstrap has a useful role to play in comparing models as in variable selection in logistic regression that Gail Gong studied in the 1980s.  I think it can be another way of doing sensitivity analysis

Comment: Hi @MichaelChernick [don't be loopy](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/183-2007.pdf)

Comment: @Laurent Thanks for that reference.  My mention of R vs SAS was mainly just a concern.  I know that knowledgeable people have written about how just about anything can be done reasonably in R and I know it has been debated on this site.  I may have commented on this myself and had R programmers tell me that things like traceability can be handled in R.  My understanding of the FDA review process is that the lead reviewer has a lot of authority and does not always appreciate the statistical issues and can make illogical rulings.

Comment: Companies can overcome these problems but it can be more of a headache than they are willing to take on.  I think in my consulting situation they preferred to go with the flow rather than challenge and do the correct analysis.

Comment: @AndyW I recall my involvement in the post from the first link and that is why I said that the experts gave me the impression that R can do  everything in a way that is/should be acceptable to the FDA.  I trusted the comments and did not followup with the links provided since it wasn't my question and I wasn't as vested in the answers as I am now!  Thanks for bringing it all to my attention.

Comment: I think the comments address a lot of my concerns.  What could be left for an answer is a description of what my client would need to do to validate the R solution I give them.  Is there anything in the federal regulations or FDA Guidances that can support a waiver of validation of software (just in case the issue is raised in the next submission round)?

Answer (score 3):

We have done tons of submission to the FDA with R.
The Agency do not prefer a software versus the other.

Comment: Yes - see here: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/06/fda-r-ok.html

Comment: @Samer: Is it possible to trace some R submissions to the FDA? Is there a repository online to see all R submissions?